# Reading only modified data

Tags: node.js, file, file-io, filestream

In my project, i am using `fs.watchFile` for listening to the modification of the text file.

**Requirement**
Read only the last updated data

**Note** In text file data is always added, no deletion.

**Sample code**

```
fs.watchFile(config.filePath, function (curr, prev) {
        fs.readFile(config.filePath, function (err, data) {
              if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        });
 });
```

Above code reads whole text file when the file is modified.

Any suggestion will be greatful.

**Working Code**

```
fs.watchFile(config.filePath, function (curr, prev) {
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(config.filePath,{start:prev.size,end:curr.size,encoding:"utf-8");
    filestream.on('data', function (data) {
         console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the stat object of the file. The curr and the prev object are both [Stat](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)s objects and have an attribute called "size".

I assume you are always adding data to the beginning or the end of the file, otherwise there is no way in knowing where the data was added.

The difference between prev.size and curr.size tells you how many bytes were added. By give the [readFile-Function](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) an options object with a start and an end attribute.

For example: You always add to the end, then you can make such a call:

```
fs.readFile(config.filePath, {start: prev.size}, function ...);
```

If you add in the beginning:

```
fs.readFile(config.filePath, {start: 0, end: (curr.size-prev.size)}, function ...);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: FYI, I am appending the data at end of file. But it is not working fs.readFile(config.filePath, {start: prev.size}, function ...); Its read entire file.

Comment: Thanks your answer gives me an idea +1.